# tslint exclude not working for tsoa routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, tslint

I want to exclude the routes.ts file which is created by tsoa routes from tslint compiler option. I tried exclude option, Still no success.
exclude option is working for remaining files, am facing issue only with routes.ts which is generated by tsoa routes.

This is my tsconfig json

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "outputdir/mysrc",
    "rootDir": "mysrc",
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  },
  "filesglob": [
    "typings",
    "mysrc/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "outputdir",
    "mysrc/routes/routes.ts",
    "mysrc/helpers/temp.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}`

Comment: We're going to need more information.  At a minimum, please add your `tslint.json` file to the question.  The fastest way to resolve this might be if you can publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have `mysrc/routes/routes.ts` in the wrong config file. You don't want that in `tsconfig.json` you want it in `tslint.json` as follows:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
  }
  linterOptions: {
    "exclude: [
      "mysrc/routes/routes.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can read more here: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/